# Customize drupal search result page

Tags: drupal

I have created a customized theme called "test", and I am trying to display the search results.

I added the function test_preprocess_search_results() to the template.php (copied the code from drupal page "function template_preprocess_search_results", then copy the search-result.tpl.php from search module to the "test"'s template folder.

`function test_preprocess_search_results(&$variables) {
      $variables['search_results'] = '';
      if (!empty($variables['module'])) {
           $variables['module'] = check_plain($variables['module']);
      }
      foreach ($variables['results'] as $result) {
           $variables['search_results'] .= theme('search_result', array('result' => $result, 'module' => $variables['module']));
      }
       $variables['pager'] = theme('pager', array('tags' => NULL));
       $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'search_results__' . $variables['module'];
}`

I am new in drupal, my concern is how can I make the search result display in some certain div  which claimed in my page.tpl.php file? Do something like `<?php print render($page['search_result']); ?>` in page.tpl.php div ? I am not sure how does the default theme know where to display the search result? Can anyone help thanks

ps: after what I did, and refresh the cache, nothing show up

Answer (score 1):

For search results you should use the **search-results.tpl.php** (all results list) and **search-result.tpl.php** (single list item) templates. Copy them from ROOT/modules/search folder into your theme folder and override them as you prefer.